# Is there alternation of generations in animals other than cnidarians?

Tags: zoology, reproduction, life-history

Are there other animals besides cnidarians that exhibit alternation of generations (having distinct sexual and asexual life stages)? If so, what are these animals? Further, why do so few animals have this kind of life cycle? What are the evolutionary advantages of such a life cycle, and why are cnidarians emphasized in zoology?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, each question should be posted separately — this improves the chances that you will get answers for each question and makes the answers more accessible for future users. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: Also note that you are using [alternation of generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternation_of_generations) differently from any usage I have ever encountered. I encourage you to change this to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikiwand the [heterogamy](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Asexual_reproduction) occurs also in:

- some aphids
- several rotifer species
- Daphnia (freshwater crustacean)